# Can I generate ad revenues with my own FB app?

Tags: facebook, ads

I wanted to ask if I create an app within FB can I generate ad revenues that come to me and not FB?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, provided you use one of these companies: https://developers.facebook.com/adproviders/

Comment: haven't come across this page before, +1

Comment: @ifaour - it's linked from the main policy documentation

Comment: ah...then this is the reason ;-)